# SQL: Search for unallowed characters as given in one column and replace

Tags: mysql, sql, database, replace, pattern-matching

Allowed characters are 0-9 A-Z a-z and .-_

Ich want to search in MySQL Database in one column if there some other characters as allowed and replace them with "-".

Is it possible with SQL?

Something like this ;)

> @ARRAY = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.,-,_,A-Z,a-z);
>
> UPDATE table SET columnName = replace(columnName, 'CHAR DOES NOT MATCH @ARRAY', '-');

UPDATE:

```
ID  NUMBER

1   1620WGC-2018_3.2
2   70-30-2015
3   PTMMC4450-2017+
4   PE-1013-64/2018
5   1580-2018_3%2
6   PE-1036-68A-2018
7   D10+
```

In Column NUMBER the ID's 3,4,5 and 7 shoud be corrected to:

```
ID  NUMBER

1   1620WGC-2018_3.2
2   70-30-2015
3   PTMMC4450-2017-
4   PE-1013-64-2018
5   1580-2018_3-2
6   PE-1036-68A-2018
7   D10-
```

because +,/, and %, for example, are not in Array with allowed charakters.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: Server-Version: 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu)

Comment: If you are able to run v8, there is a REGEXP_REPLACE function which will do what you need

Comment: No way, I can use just 5.7

Comment: provide some better example data.. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "Help others reproduce the problem"

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have edited my question.

Comment: Still none existing table structure.with example data, so iam going to voteclose this question to be unclear.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I hope now you can better understand what I want to reach

Answer (score 0):

You might need this.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE replace(replace(columnName, '\'', ''), '-', '') = 'findMyText'
```

Comment: I don't think so. I have some allowed characters. They shouldn't be changed, but all other different characters (if there some of them) as allowed should replaced with "-".